# What fields in a digitally signed Email are signed?

Tags: digital-signature, email-attachments

I want to buy a digital certificate to sign my emails.

Do the attached files in a digitally signed email are automatically signed as well or do i have to sign it separately?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are off topic in regards to SSL.

1. I think you are interested in PGP(Pretty Good Privacy) encryption.
2. You don't need to buy anything, programs to create public-private keys are open-source and freely available from lots of sources, as are public key repositories if choose to post your public key.
3. While PGP is an encryption standard it can also be used to sign you emails with a private key so your recipient whom has your private can be reasonably sure you sent it.
4. Most email apps have some form of either manually or automatically either (a) encrypting your email(including attachments) (b) signing your email with your private key so receiver can confirm you sent it.

Comment: The OP was asking about S/MIME, not about PGP/MIME (which is an alternative technology). So your answer is not applicable.